# How can we assign a permission to all users in Keycloak Authorization Services policies?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, redhat-sso, keycloak-authorization-services

I would like to create a all users policy in Keycloak:

[image]

How can I specify that this policy is for all users?

Using '*' didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I specify that this policy is for all users? Using '*' didn't
> work.

Having a policy for all users is kind of unusual I would say.

Nonetheless, You can try to create a default Realm role, so all users will get that role, and then create a policy-based on that role.